# How to describe holding a child with hands in such a way that the child doesn't touch the ground?

Tags: word-choice

How would little children ask their parents in English to hold them with their hands in such a way that the children are fully in the parents' hands and are not touching the ground with any part of their body?

I was thinking of "Mommy, please, hold me with your hands", but then I thought that one can be held with hands (by someone) while still standing on the ground - like hugging.

My second guess was "Please, carry me with your hands", but carrying implies not only holding something or someone but also walking, while what I want to describe is a situation, in which the parent would be standing (like, for example, a mother and her daughter are standing and watching a street clown's performance and the girl can't see the clowns because of the crowd, she asks her mom to hold her with her hands).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A child can say to a parent

> Please pick me up.

if the child wants to be held in the parent's arms, for example,  if the child is tired from walking.

If the child wants to be lifted higher in order to be able to see over the heads of a crowd

> Hold me up (so I can see).

or

> Lift me up (so I can see).

Answer (score 2):

Very small children just say, "Up" or "Carry"

A little older and they will say, "Pick me up" or "Carry me."